# assisatnce in the sql function

Tags: sql

I have posted below written code earlier and got the correct code with the removal of errors, but my criteria is not satisfying, below is the raw data im passing as the paramater

```
 2007:10113:/I/69071/MLI/Eldridge
```

and in return the output should be  "69071", for this i have given the below function but im not gettig the output,a nd i have kept some other condition to satisfy other requirements also, please help me.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  --2007:10113:/I/69071/MLI/Eldridge
go
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Empnum] (@RAWDATA NVARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
 AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TEMP1 NVARCHAR(300), @EMPNUM NVARCHAR(10), @TEMP2 NVARCHAR(300), @TEMP3 NVARCHAR(300)
SET @TEMP3 = 'Disabled'
SET @EMPNUM=''
SET @TEMP2 = @RAWDATA
IF( CHARINDEX(@TEMP3,@RAWDATA,1) = 0) 
BEGIN
--   SET @EMPNUM='11'
 IF ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,1,1)) = 1
      BEGIN     
 --             
       IF((LEN(@RAWDATA) - LEN(REPLACE(@TEMP2,'/','')))>1)
             BEGIN
             SET @RAWDATA=SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,CHARINDEX('/',@RAWDATA)+1,LEN(@RAWDATA))    
              SET @RAWDATA=SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,CHARINDEX('/',@RAWDATA)+1,LEN(@RAWDATA))    
               SET @RAWDATA=SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,1,CHARINDEX('/',@RAWDATA)-1)
  IF( CHARINDEX('*C',@RAWDATA) = 0 OR
     CHARINDEX('CV',@RAWDATA) = 0 OR
     CHARINDEX('AV',@RAWDATA) = 0 OR
     CHARINDEX('LV',@RAWDATA) = 0 ) 
      BEGIN 
         SET @EMPNUM = ''
         RETURN @EMPNUM
     END
  ELSE 
     BEGIN
         IF ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,1,1)) = 1
             BEGIN
                 SET @EMPNUM = @RAWDATA
                 RETURN @EMPNUM
          END 
 ELSE
     IF((SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,1,1)='C') AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,2,1)) = 1)
         BEGIN
             SET @EMPNUM = SUBSTRING(@RAWDATA,2,LEN(@RAWDATA))
             RETURN @EMPNUM
         END
END
 END
END
END
  RETURN @EMPNUM
 END
```

Comment: Why is it not working; what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error in my code, and changed the "="o "<>"

```
IF( CHARINDEX('*C',@RAWDATA) <> 0 OR
 CHARINDEX('CV',@RAWDATA) <> 0 OR
 CHARINDEX('AV',@RAWDATA) <> 0 OR
 CHARINDEX('LV',@RAWDATA) <> 0 ) 
 BEGIN 
     SET @EMPNUM = ''
     RETURN @EMPNUM
 END
```